# I cannot run tests in clojure/midje

Tags: import, clojure, namespaces, midje

I run tests with:

```
lein midje :autotest
```

And I get error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: No namespace: sprint-is.json-export found

File is in: sprint-is/src/sprint_is/json_export.clj

It contains code:

```
(ns sprint-is.json-export)
(require [[noir.response :as response]])
(defn serialize [value] (response/json value))
```

It throws this error even when I don't have no test file. When I create test file, I get similar error:

No namespace: sprint-is.test.json-export found

Test is in: sprint-is/test/sprint_is/json_export.clj

And contains:

```
(ns sprint-is.test.json-export
    (:require [sprint-is.json-export :as json-export]))

(fact "module can serialize scalar values"
    (json-export/serialize 123) => 123)
```

When I try to import it from REPL, it cannot find the namespaces too. I tried to rename file, move files, rename directories, remove ns (it compiles but it doesn't work), asked on Clojure IRC. I compared the code with other projects (including those working on my computer) and it seems same.

Source code is here: https://bitbucket.org/jiriknesl/sprintis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a compilation error in one of your namespaces, I suspect `sprint-is.json-export`

On bitbucket, you have this:

```
(ns sprint-is.json-export)

(require [[noir.response :as response]])

(defn serialize [value] (response/json value))
```

which won't compile because `noir.response` and `response` are not defined.

you should have:

```
(ns sprint-is.json-export
   (:require [noir.response :as response]))

(defn serialize [value] (response/json value))
```

If you insist on using `require` outside of the `ns` macro, you can do the following, but be aware this is not *idiomatic* usage.

```
(ns sprint-is.json-export)

(require '[noir.response :as response])

(defn serialize [value] (response/json value))
```